# DirectX rendering issue

Tags: windows, mobile, directx

I am working in a project where I am building two version of application native win32 and Windows Store App.

My rendering  code is working in win32 but in Windows store app the screen is blank with clear color. I tried to debug the issue and captured some frame from Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostic tool. Interestingly the capture frame is showing full rendered screen with all objects showing (while the actual rendering window is blank)!

Can anyone give me some clue, what can be the issue?

Comment: Windows desktop apps use a different render loop than the UWP ICoreWindow model. As a test, try creating both kinds of apps using this [VS 2015 template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/raw/master/VSIX/Direct3DUWPGame.vsix)--for a description of the template, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx).

Comment: As I mentioned, the diagnostic tool could capture the full rendered screen.
If it was not rendering at all, will that be visible in screen capture?

Comment: The VSPIX tool is showing you the render target. It might be that are having problems with the front-buffer present swap chain.